# Как разрешить autoplay для видео в Safari на MacOS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, видео, safari, next.js

Мне нужно видео на фоне секции, на всех браузерах работает, кроме Safari, и только с MacOS я так полагаю, потому что с Iphone autoplay есть. Я использую next.js и typescript.
В браузере сафари все что я вижу это первый кадр видео и кнопку play, после нажатия на которую уже запускается просмотр видео. Можно ли это как-то обойти и что бы видео запускалось сразу после перехода на страницу?

Вот кнопка, я так понимаю это стандартные controls для видео в Safari:

[image: Кнопка Play]

```
const videoReqUrl =
  "https://...";

const GetHeroComponent = async () => {
  const videoReq = await fetch(videoReqUrl);
  const video = await videoReq.json();

  return (
    <video
      className={s.hero__video}
      width="100%"
      height="100%"
      autoPlay
      playsInline
      loop
      muted
    >
      <source src={video.acf.hero_video_webm} type="video/webm" />
      <source src={video.acf.hero_video_mp4} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
};

export default GetHeroComponent;
```